# how to get Cookies Value From WebBrowser Control to Textbox in vb

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, session-cookies

I am finding how to get Cookies From WebBrowser Control to TextBox in Form of VB.

Example cookies that i checked on another software but i need it transfer to TextBox
CFID=683314; CFTOKEN=29469955

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

`TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie`